# bit operations?

Tags: sqlite, bit

I have constructed an SQLite table for my DVD collection.  I have a field 'Genre' with the following values: Adventure, Animation, Biography, Christmas, Comedy, Crime, ..., Western.  The 'Genre' field is of type int, where each bit of the integer represents one of the 24 genres.  For example if bit 4 is set, the DVD is a comedy.  I want to be able to retrieve a subset of the table based on the genre.  For example, I tried this:

```
SELECT * FROM AV WHERE GENRE & 1 << 4 > 0 ORDER BY Title
```

to retrieve all of the comedys.  Oddly enough, the SQL statement executed OK, but not with the expected results.

I know I can just store the genres as a VarChar, but I would like to make it work by storing the genres as bits in an integer.

Comment: Why would you do it this way....?  Why not just say Adventure films are `1` and Animation are `2`, etc.?  It sounds like you're just trying to do something fancy with how you're storing it for the sake of doing something fancy, but it just sounds like a headache to store/query.

Comment: Please consider switching to a normalized data model :-) Those tricks are 99% of the time not needed.

Comment: I appreciate the fact you're trying to play with bit flags, but can you at least post some sample data?  What do these tables look like, and what results are you getting?

Comment: If your DVDs can each have multiple genres, you should have a detail table (e.g. `AV_GENRE`) relating back to your `AV` table, instead of trying to do bit manipulation on a single field in `AV`.

Comment: Works as expected for me.

Answer (score 0):

My bad.  The SQL statement does work correctly.  I had added two genres and then sorted the genres alphabetically which changed the bit locations.  Sorry for the confusion.
Earl Staley